# Why "G.nodes[1]['key']" has error? TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

I am using Python 3.5 to write a very short program:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.MultiGraph()
G.add_node(1, key=1,rank=1)
print(G.nodes[1]['key'])
```

I want to add a node to the graph G with key=1,rank=1 and then print the key value of this node . But after running it, Python gives the following error:

> TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

It seems that the error happens in:

```
print(G.nodes[1]['key'])
```

Could anyone help me ?

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with this issue as well and found that I had old version (1.x) of NetworkX. The [migration guide](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/release/migration_guide_from_1.x_to_2.0.html) explains what changed with respect to `G.nodes`. To update the package and fix the issue just run

`pip install networkx --upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

`nodes` is [a method](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes.graph.html#iterating-over-nodes-and-edges), you need to call it.

```
G.nodes()[1]['key']
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I used  G.nodes()[1]['key'] , but it gives the following error: IndexError: list index out of range